# Remove double quotes with escape character from JSON string

Tags: apex, json

I have a JSON like below,

```
String jsonStr='{"key":"value \"subvalue\""}';
```

I want to deserialize it with `JSON.deserilizeuntyped` method due to unexpected characters. I have tried

```
jsonStr.replace('\\"','');
```

But still not able to get rid of the \" from the JSON string. Any suggestions?
I want the string as {"key":"value subvalue"}

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the problem is that your source code isn't encoded properly. You need to escape the backslashes:

```java
    String jsonStr='{"key":"value \\"subvalue\\""}';
    System.debug(json.deserializeuntyped(jsonstr));
```

Note that in the actual JSON, there would only be a single backslash. Apex requires backslashes to be escaped in source code.

Comment: I want the string like {"key":"value subvalue"}